# is this the right way to declare a prototype in MASM?

Tags: assembly, masm

I am new to Assembly and I wrote a simple program that does nothing but call a procedure call `_ExitProgram` that then calls `ExitProcess` from Windows.

There is no compilation error when I place `_ExitProgram` above main procedure, but when I place it below the main procedure my compiler cannot recognize the function `_ExitProgram`. I would like to know how to declare a procedure in a proper way.
anyone please.
Thanks

```
.386

.MODEL FLAT, STDCALL

OPTION CASEMAP : NONE

;###################################################

;IMPORT FUNCTIONS

ExitProcess PROTO STDCALL, :DWORD


;LOCAL FUNCTONS

_ExitProgram PROTO STDCALL, :DWORD

;###################################################

.code

_start:

    push ebp

    mov ebp, esp 

        invoke _ExitProgram, 0

    pop ebp

    ret

end _start

;##################################################

_ExitProgram PROC STDCALL, uExitCode:DWORD

    invoke ExitProcess, uExitCode

    ret

_ExitProgram ENDP

;##################################################

END
```

I am using visual studio 2017 and get the following:

```
1>Assembling main.asm...

1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __ExitProgram@4

1>C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\test\Debug\test.exe : 

fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

1>Done building project "pack.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: `END` must be the very last directive. Therefore move `end _start` to the end and delete the `END` there.

Comment: It really worked thanks.